# How do I interpret this object in Google Chrome's console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

In my Google Chrome console, I get this output when I do `console.log(MyObject)`:

```
MyObject {name: null, place: null}
  name: "Don"
  place: "United States"
```

How should this be interpreted? `console.log(MyObject.name)` returns null, but the console also says that it is set.

Comment: how do you create your object? Could it be that you have those properties in the instance as well as in the prototype?

Comment: I just found out that Google chrome's console prints a string when you do console.log(), but when you twirl open that object, it shows you the values at that time. So if you did some timer, the first line will say 0seconds... and the lines below will say like 74 seconds, or whatever time you twirl open the object. Annoying.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's interesting and good to know. I guess you could post an answer by yourself.